# How to get only specific items from list in Python

Tags: python

I would like to get only specific items `(A027SRR,B09P4RR,C09QMRR,C09MIRR,A026SRR,A0CDDRR,B0NOTRR)` from the list but unfortunately is not working and I dont know where is an issue.Thank you

```
items = ['A027SRR', '0.00', '', 'B09P4RR', '852.00', '', 'C09QMRR', '309.60', '', 'C09MIRR', '18.70', '', 'A026SRR', '78.40', '', 'A0CDDRR', 'B0NOTRR', '', '1543.52', '1481.52', "VIP discount :   20.01%  \VIP discount's information"]
for f in items[:]:   # check if character is number then check if is empty then if is lower case then chceck if lenght is seven 
    if f.isdigit() == True and f =='' and f.islower()== True and len(f) != 7 :          
    items.remove(f)
print(" Items are : " + str(items))
```

Comment: You're checking whether the string is only digits, *and* is empty, *and* is lower case… What string possibly fulfils all of those criteria at once?! Did you mean `or`, not `and`…?!

Comment: The "items.remove" needs to indented more, in order to be executed in the if-block

Comment: @ MisterMiyagi yes ,I mean that string cannot be empty and digit at the same time

Comment: You should also describe the condition on which you choose to keep the elements.

Comment: Note that ``items : ...`` does not define a variable called ``items``. It only defines its type (meaninglessly).

Comment: @deceze I mean fulfils all of those criteria at one

Comment: Again… what string is simultaneously empty *and* lower case *and* digits?! You want all strings that fulfil *any* of those criteria (!?), meaning you want `or`, not `and`.

Comment: I think, you should consider using regular expressions instead.

Comment: It may be beneficial to check whether a string satisfies your format, instead of rejecting various strings that do not. What exactly is your criteria for valid strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a regex solution:

```
If a string is having atleast 1 Upper Case letter and atleast 1 number and is of length 7
```

---

```
reg=re.compile("^(?=.{7}$)(?=.*\d)(?=.*[A-Z]).*")
list(filter(reg.search, items))
```

---

```
['A027SRR', 'B09P4RR', 'C09QMRR', 'C09MIRR', 'A026SRR', 'A0CDDRR', 'B0NOTRR']
```

Answer (score -1):

Simply use the filter function and convert it to a list. You do not state the criteria based on which you want to filter. As per your question, you want to remove an item if any one of those conditions are true not if all of them are true. Which means you'll have to use `or` to separate the conditions. Also `isdigit()` and `islower()` already return `True` or `False`, you don't need to check it with another `True`, `isdigit()` instead of `isdigit() == True`

```
final_list = list(filter(lambda f: not (f.isdigit() or f =='' or f.islower() or len(f) != 7), items[:]))
```

You can also use `any`:

```
final_list = list(filter(lambda f: not any([f.isdigit(),f =='', f.islower(),len(f) != 7]), items[:]))
```

Since you do not want to keep the items if the condition is true, you can use `itertools.filterfalse`, you will not have to add the `not`:

```
from itertools import filterfalse
final_list = list(filterfalse(lambda f: f.isdigit() or f =='' or f.islower() or len(f) != 7, items[:]))
```